# A multilevel list with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, list, codeigniter

I'm newly working with CodeIgniter and PHP. I'm trying to do a simple task that is to show a multilevel menu. Let's say I have a student and status table. I want to show which students are under which status(senior, junior etc.). But I'm getting this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/sview.php

Line Number: 31
```

At line 31 i have

```
<?php echo $status->statusname;?>
```

The controller:

```
// ....
$data['status'] = $this->status_model->get_students();
$this->load->view('sview', $data);
```

The model:

```
function get_students(){

    $s = $this->db->get('status');

    foreach ($s->result() as $status){

        $students = $this->db->get_where('student', array('status_id'=>$status->id));
        $status->students = students->result();
    }

    return $s;
}
```

view:

```
<?php foreach($s as $status):?>
    <h4><?php echo $status->statusname;?></h4>
    <?php foreach($status->student as $student):?>
        <?php echo $student->studentname; ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: what do your data tables look like

Comment: Not related to your error message, but your model has a syntax error it looks like: `$status->students = students->result();` should be `$status->students = $students->result();` (missing $)

Comment: i dont know codeignigter but your model function get_students looks suspicious. you are returning $s;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not modifying `$s` in the loop in `get_students()` so it is just returning the original query of all the records from the *status* table. You're also missing a '$' on the `$students` variable in your loop.

Try this your model:

```
function get_students()
{
    $s = $this->db->get('status');

    $statuses = array();

    foreach ($s->result() as $status)
    {
        $students = $this->db->get_where('student', array('status_id'=>$status->id));
        $status->students = $students->result();

        $statuses[] = $status;
    }

    return $statuses;
}
```

That will return the modified `$status` variables in the `$statuses` array and then you can access them in your views.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is setting `$data['status']` up with all the different statuses it looks like.  Try changing the following in your view:

```
<?php foreach($status as $s):?>
    <h4><?php echo $s->statusname;?></h4>
    <?php foreach($s->student as $student):?>
        <?php echo $student->studentname; ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```